# Why does Qt have to be built from source for cross-compilation?

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling

I need to build a Qt app for ARM.  So many pages like [this one](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/) show that I have to build Qt from source using a lengthy process.  Why is this necessary?  Can't I just change the target platform inside Qt Creator, which I find under `Tools > Options > Build & Run > Compilers`?

I am a bit surprise at this, because Eclipse CDT does not require such process.  It seems to suggest that I must different Qt installations for each specific platform.  This seems like a bad design. Could someone enlighten me on this?

Comment: Is there a set of the Qt libraries pre-built for your target? Available directly from inside Qt Creator? Then sure go ahead and use that. But if there isn't a pre-built set of libraries then you need to build them yourself.

Comment: How do I check if the set of libraries are available for my target platform or not?  I am new to Qt, so please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "Eclipse CDT does not require such process"? If you want to build for ARM with some libraries, you do need ARM versions of those libraries. If it works out of the box with Eclipse CDT, where does it get the ARM libraries, I am curious.

Comment: The toolchain for ARM G++ comes from Linaro.  Eclipse CDT does not need to be built for use with ARM.

Comment: If Qt itself supports a given target, then compiling it is, in most cases, very easy - it takes long, but you do it only once, and you should script it so that you a) don't forget how you did it, b) ensure you can make it a part of your continuous integration process, c) can track changes to build process in your version control system, d) can share a tested and reproducible process with others, etc. If Qt supports the target, all you need is a `configure` call with proper arguments, followed by `make -jN` and `make -jN install`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of the explanation the difference should be pointed out between:

- the *LIBRARY*, i.e. the code provided by Qt

and

- the *CODE* that uses the library, i.e. the code written by you.

In order to spare the time of compiling the *LIBRARY* over and over again, as it does not change so frequently (amongst other reasons), it is compiled once and then the compiled binaries are linked in the *CODE*.

`Tools > Options > Build & Run > Compilers` allows you to add tools to compile the *CODE* for the target platform, **provided** you have the binaries compiled by someone, e.g. Qt, for **the same** platform.

If no one have done that and (most importantly) made the binaries available to you, then you have to do it by yourself, meaning that you have to build the *LIBRARY* from its sources.

To see if there are official precompiled binaries for your target platform, please check [the offline installers](https://www1.qt.io/offline-installers/) page.

Comment: This seems to be the right direction.  Can you tell me how I can check if the binaries for target platform(s) are compiled or not?

Comment: @J.Doe, unless someone have kindly provided such binaries somewhere on the Internet, the answer is _yes_ (*build it from sources). And now you know why.

Comment: thank you so much.  I really know why now.  All the guides I read never mention the reason why they build Qt from source.